# significance of embedded_in in mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, polymorphism

I am trying to understand the relationships in mongoid and not able to move past the following:

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :photos
end

class Photo
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :Band
end
```

In the above code, Instructing Band to embed_many phtos shall store full photo data inside Band. However, what is the need to put embedded_in inside Photo class? If we do not put embedded_in in Photo, will it not be polymorphic automatically?

Also, will the query `Photo.all` fetch photos embedded inside Bands? If yes, Is this the reason for embedded_in? Can we have multiple embedded_in's for one class?

Comment: Polymorphism has to do with a Photo being part of Band or another object AFAIK. Did you mean "encapsulated" instead of "polymorphic"? A Band has many photos - allowing you to access photos from band. A Photo is can be embedded in a Band, allowing you - given a Photo - access the band it is in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `embedded_in` call is needed to add the methods to the `Photo` class so that you can access the band in which the photo is embedded. Just like you use `has_many` and `belongs_to` although the foreign key is only stored in the object that has a `belongs_to`. It also adds [methods to check if the Photo is persisted](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/relations/embedded/in.rb#L89) and so on. And yes, [you can have multiple `embedded_in` for one class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349432/mongoid-embedding-a-document-in-multiple-documents).

`Photo.all` will not give you the photos that are embedded inside other classes. Normaly, if you only access a model through another, you'd embed it. It's cheaper to fetch the whole document at once than have another round-trip to the database when using a relation with a foreign key. So if you need something like `Photo.all` you should not embed `Photo`.